# How to subscribe to other user's calendars?

Tags: evolution

In all previous versions of Evolution that I had (up to the version included in Ubuntu 10.04), under File, there was an option to subscribe to other user's resources. This allowed to subscribe to shared calendars on the MS Exchange server.

But I don't see this option in Evolution 2.32.2 included in Ubuntu 11.04. How can I subscribe to shared Exchange resources?

Comment: Did you see the "Subscribe Other User's Folder" Context Menu when clicking on the Exchange account on the Mail page?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on account in mail page. Choose "subscribe to folder of other user", locate the user via the choose button and select calendar in the folder name drop down menu. Click ok, and your co-worker's calendar should be available in the calendar page under the Exchange account.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help: Connecting Evolution Mail Client to Exchange 2010
(and Exchange 2007)

[How To](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm)

[image]